# builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable in Twisted

Tags: python, tcp

I  encountered a `TypeError` when I used **[twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)** to create a TCP server.
When I run the **client.py** after starting **server.py**, I receive the error presented below in the **Error traceback** section.

I have no idea about this error. However, I am sure the error happens at `server.py`.

**server.py:**

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
    from time import ctime

    PORT = 1234
    class TserverProtocols(protocol.Protocol):
        def connectionMade(self):
            clnt = self.clnt = self.transport.getPeer().host
            print('...connected from:', clnt)
        def dataReceived(self, data):
            self.transport.write(('[%s] %s' %(ctime(),data)).encode())

    factory = protocol.Factory()
    factory.protocols = TserverProtocols
    print('waiting for connetion...')
    reactor.listenTCP(PORT, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

**client.py:**

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 1234

class TSClntProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def sendData(self):
        data = input('>')
        if data:
            print('...sending %s' % data)
            self.transport.write(data.encode())
        else:
            self.transport.loseConnetion()

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendData()

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print(data)
        self.sendData()

class TSCFactorty(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = TSClntProtocol
    clientConnetionLost = clientConnectionFailed = lambda slef, connector, reason:reactor.stop()

reactor.connectTCP(HOST, PORT, TSCFactorty())
reactor.run()
```

**Error traceback:**

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 86, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 122, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 85, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 597, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1069, in doRead
    protocol = self.factory.buildProtocol(self._buildAddr(addr))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 133, in buildProtocol
    p = self.protocol()
builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several typos in your code. Regarding your question, you should replace in server.py

```
factory.protocols = TserverProtocols
```

with

```
factory.protocol = TserverProtocols
```